# How to select only one feature of a vector layer from a drop down list using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wfs

I am working on a project using OpenLayers(v5.3.0) and javascript which displays a vector layer. Using a dropdown list , vector layer features can be selected.

Now the project works like, when I select a feature from dropdown list, it is displayed as selected. When I select another feature, the previous one is also displayed as selected with it.The previously selected feature is not getting unselected.

My requirement is to select one  feature at a time.How can I achieve this. My code is given below.

```
function selectByDistrict(selectiddist) {
  var view = new ol.View({
    projection: projection
  });

  var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    layers: function(layer) {
      return layer.get('typename') == 'layerDIST';
    },
    style: [myStyle]
  });
  var districtName = document.getElementById('selectiddist').options[document.getElementById('selectiddist').selectedIndex].text;

  var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();
  selectedFeatures.clear();
  var features = layerDIST.getSource().getFeatures();

  if (features) {
    for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
      if (features[i].get('DISTRICT') == districtName) {
        feature = features[i];
        selectedFeatures.push(feature);
        //set style for selected feature 
        feature.setStyle(myStyle);
        var polygon = selectedFeatures.getArray();
        var extent = feature.getGeometry();

        var size = (map.getSize());
        view.fit(
          extent,
          size
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A select interaction is used to select features using a pointer.  You should avoid using it when selecting by other means  You cannot force the interaction to select a feature, which is why you are having to set the style - so you must also clear that style when deselecting:

```
function selectByDistrict(selectiddist) {
  var view = new ol.View({
    projection: projection
  });

  var districtName = document.getElementById('selectiddist').options[document.getElementById('selectiddist').selectedIndex].text;

  var features = layerDIST.getSource().getFeatures();

  if (features) {
    for (i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
      if (features[i].get('DISTRICT') == districtName) {
        feature = features[i];
        //set style for selected feature 
        feature.setStyle(myStyle);
        var extent = feature.getGeometry();

        var size = (map.getSize());
        view.fit(
          extent,
          size
        );
      } else {
        feature.setStyle();
      }
    }
  }
}
```